# ¿Cómo activar i18n en yii2 con advanced template?

Tags: php, yii2, i18n

En la red me he topado con este tutorial https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831288/yii2-translation-does-not-work, 
lo he seguido pero al momento de ejecutar la extracción de mensajes en el paso 5, me aparece este error en la consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el fichero config para la consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si es un proyecto funcional que tiene instaladas varias extensiones, 
Esta es la configuracion de yii para la ejecucion del batch

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta que planteas es demasiado genérica. Intenta editar y usar texto en lugar de una imagen, además de detallar exactamente qué has hecho y cómo reproducirlo.

Comment: Estimado pon tu código del config para ver si detectamos algo ¿has instalado soft de 3ro? o ¿es un proyecto recién generado de la terminal?

Comment: He leido que con indicar al servicelocator el uso de la clase 'user' en el config.main de la consola ya deberia de funcionar, pero sigue con errores

Comment: puedes ingresar a esta sala de chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32679/ayuda-a-usuarios-nuevos

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq ... lo siento aun no puedo usarlo

Comment: cierto! te deje escritas algunas ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder habilitar la traducción y que quede disponible para el backend como para el frontend debes crear una carpeta dentro de la carpeta common llamada messages, debe quedar así:

```
common
   |
   +---> messages
```

Dentro de la carpeta messages, creas una carpeta que contendrá la traducción que deseas, en caso de que sean traducciones al ingles esta carpeta podría llamarse 'en', hasta acá la estructura de carpetas

```
common
   |
   +---> messages
            |
            +---->es
```

Ya teniendo esta estructura, debe crear un archivo llamado por convención "app.php", este archivo contendrá la traudcción especifica de un idioma de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
    return [
        'Hola' => 'Hello',
        'Mundo' => 'World'
    ];
```

Hasta aquí tenemos nuestra configuración creada, para habilitarla en Yii se debe habilitar el componente i18n en el archivo common/config/main-local.php

```
'components' => [
    ....
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                # El archivo de traducciones se encuentra en:
                # folder/to/project/common/messages
                'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                # Para el componente la variable sourceLanguage 
                # siempre debe estar por defecto 'en-US'
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    ....
]
```

Con esto ya tenemos habilitada la traducción, para establecer cuál traducción tendrá la aplicación por defecto se estable en mail-local.php

```
<?php 
    return [
        ....
        'language' => 'en' # El proyecto se inicializa con la traducción en inglés
        ....
        components => [
            ....
        ],
    ....
    ]
```

Ya para tener los textos traducibles, en las vistas solo debe utilizar la función nativa de Yii:

```
<div>
    <label> <?= Yii::t('app', 'Hola') ?> </label>
    <label> <?= Yii::t('app', 'Mundo') ?> </label>
</div>
```

Puede seguir agregando mas soporte para mas idiomas creando mas carpetas en common/messages con las subcarpetas y archvios de traduccioes que desea soportar para la aplicación.

Answer (score 3):

El componente `user` en Yii2 por defecto tiene la clase `yii\web\User` la cual se usa para obtener la información del usuario cuando entras a Yii2 desde un navegador web.

En consola esta clase no esta disponible por defecto y hay que darla de alta o usar otra clase equivalente para consola (ya sea desarrollada por tí o de 3ros).

Recomiendo añadir:

```
'class' => 'yii\web\User',
```

A tu componente `user` en la configuración de consola o **evitar usarlo** debido a que dicho componente no está diseñado para usar en consola, esto con la razón que en consola no hay autenticación de usuarios como en la web ni recepción de parámetros por medio de form, para ello hay clases que puedes encontrar en la [página de la documentación oficial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html) escribiendo en el buscador: ***yii\console***.

Las clases ahí listadas tienen propiedades y métodos que pueden ser usados para crear componentes que interactuen por medio de la consola.

**Más información oficial (inglés) sobre:**

- User: [yii\web\User - Yii Framework 2.0 API Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html)
- IdentityInterface: [yii\web\IdentityInterface - Yii Framework 2.0 API Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-identityinterface.html)

Saludos.

Comment: Al utilizar esa clase en el componente me da este error:                  Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown prop
erty: yii\console\ErrorHandler::errorAction' ....... así le declare en los componentes del config de consola:    'user' => [
             'class' => 'yii\web\User',
          ],

Comment: Le probe en una aplicacion nueva con advanced template, el cual me indicaba el mismo error del usuario al momento de realizar la migracion del RBAC y se  soluciono con lo que mencionaste en esta respuesta...

Comment: @unrealmach me da gusto que te haya funcionado, si consideras que ésta repuesta es la correcta puedes marcarla con palomita.